# MySQL Queries to Find Specific Customers

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL Table as

```
customerID  productID dateofPurchase                        special
10          1234       2010-12-06 00:00:00.0                 NO
10          2345       2010-12-07 00:00:00.0                 YES
11          1245       2010-12-08 00:00:00.0                 NO
```

I have sorted the table by `customerID` and then by `dateofPurchase.`

I wanted to answer few queries and I am unable to come up with a logic.

1. If a customer has bought a special item, I would like to know the difference between the time he bought special item and most recent item purchased before the special item.
2. Count of user purchasing same item multiple times.

Comment: What have you tried?  This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Agree with the others. But will provide some search advice - for 1) - you can do 'math' on 2 dates - the MySQL documentation is very good in this area; 2) - GROUP BY will work on multiple columns (then use 'HAVING' to specify only multiple purchased items are displayed). Good luck.